# Would you say 'roles in a team' or 'roles of a team'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Bump into this phrase '**roles of an AI team**'. It is the title of one of the chapters of an online course 'AI for everyone'.

My first interpretation of this phrase is the '*roles/functions of the whole team*',(i.e. roles of an AI team including optimizing business operations, reducing business operation costs, researching into new business models, etc)

however what the instructor actually implies is the '*different roles/job titles within that 'AI team'*'. (i.e. title 'roles of an AI team' then proceed to talk about Data scientist, Data engineer, Machine Learning engineer, Machine Learning researcher, etc)

This confuses me as I would rather say '**roles in an AI team**' to imply the different job titles in that team. While '**roles of an AI team**' makes me think of the functions of the whole team on a larger scale.

But I am an English learner so I am likely to miss something here.
What would you say in this situation?

Comment: Where did you 'bump into' the phrase?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey in an online course. Do you think the instructor make a mistake? But this guy Andrew Ng happened to be a british-born American and he is the head of Google Brain, so I assume his English is ok

Comment: What online course? Where? Please provide surrounding text.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey course 'AI for everyone' on coursera taught by Andrew Ng. No surrounding text as this is the title of one chapter

Comment: It is OK to say that some **of** the roles of an AI team are Data Scientist. ...
Data Engineer. ...
ML Engineer/ML Researcher. ...
AI Software Engineer. ...
Chief AI Officer/Chief Research Officer. ...
Data Analytics Lead. ...
Member of Technical Staff. ...
AI Sponsor.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  'roles of an AI team' is the name of a chapter and the instructor proceed to list out all different roles like ML engineer/scientist, Data scientist, Date engineer, AI product manager, etc

Comment: It would help to edit into your question the information in the comments as it makes it much clearer what the problem is.

Comment: Here's the point no one is making: He guy is describing a general situation. The team has roles and people on the team have roles. Their roles **in or on the team** will vary.

Comment: Both or neither. They are not comparable.

Roles 'in a team' describes the contributions of individual members: leader, executive, administrator, accountant, (what have you)

Roles 'of a team' should rather be 'the role of the team' which quite differently, says nothing about individual members or their contributions but rather, describes the function or goal, target or mission of the team as a whole.

Comment: @DLiu I agree with your penultimate paragraph, but I think confusion is being caused by the ill advised ue of **..roles {plural} of..**.  Using **roles in** is unambiguous, it refers to the individual team members. **role of** is also unambiguous, it refers to the team as a whole, but **roles of** could mean either and is best avoided.

Answer (score 4):

A *role **of** a team* refers to *some function performed by the team **as a whole**.* Any or all of the team members may be involved in discharging that role.

A *role **in** a team* refers to *some "sub-function" **within*** the team - usually equivalent to one or more ***positions*** within the team held by the worker(s) who perform that sub-function as part of their job description.

Comment: My role in the A Team is not a sub-function. It is a main function.

Comment: If the role of any one team member is identical to the role of the entire team collectively we probably don't need the word ***role*** anyway. It's more or less implicit in any context where we use ***role*** that there will be *other* roles (performed by other people or teams or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

We can use 'of' when discussing components that make up a whole.

It is OK to say that some of the roles **of** an AI team are Data Scientist. ... Data Engineer. ... ML Engineer/ML Researcher. ... AI Software Engineer. ... Chief AI Officer/Chief Research Officer. ... Data Analytics Lead. ... Member of Technical Staff. ... AI Sponsor.

Some parts **of** a car are the engine, the wheels, the silencer, the battery, (etc).

Comment: Thanks. I think the word 'role' causes more ambiguity compare to the word 'part'. 'Parts of a car' will not be misunderstood

Comment: @DLiu - There is no ambiguity to a native speaker.

Comment: ok. I am not a native speaker so sure I am wrong.. but the 'roles of an AI team' including optimizing the company's operation process, reducing operation costs by using AI technologies, researching into new business model, etc.

Comment: @DLiu - that is another valid use of 'roles of'.

Answer (score 2):

"Roles of an AI Team" can be interpreted in multiple ways.  One version is "Duties performed-by an AI Team" as you interpret the meaning; another is "Jobs belonging-to an AI Team" which the author seems to intend.  Both meanings are valid natural uses of the English language, and the ambiguity that exists is typically resolved as more context is given. (Though, as a U.S. native speaker, I do think that I too would default to "your" interpretation in the absence of all other contextual information.)

The phrasing "Roles in an AI Team" would have been unambiguous; and thus that would probably have been better for pedagogy.

(Though, in all fairness, most STEM educators are probably focused foremost upon the logical rigor of the formulas they post far more-so than the prose that they write to encapsulate it.)

Comment: Expressed another way: the confusion is in the usage of the word "of". If it's used to mean "associated with", it refers to the team as a whole. If it's used to mean "contained in", the meaning is similar to using "in". Either is a legit usage, but it's ambiguous.

Comment: This particular chapter of the course was put off by me due to the misunderstanding. Initially I thought the content of this chapter was highly similar to another chapter named 'major AI application areas', which talks about what an AI team can achieve.